# Mongodb error failed 24 : Too many open files : Using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My code is creating pretty heavy traffic, with lots of find, update, map reduce and createIndex operations, so I am not sure which one can be the culprit, but  I am getting the following error:

```
_create_global_word_frequency_collection
    full_response=True)
  File "/Users/arj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1857, in map_reduce
    sock_info, cmd, slave_ok, ReadPreference.PRIMARY)
  File "/Users/arj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 205, in _command
    read_concern=read_concern)
  File "/Users/arj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 211, in command
    read_concern)
  File "/Users/arj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 100, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/Users/arj/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 196, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('mapreduce', u'verbatimterms'), ('map', Code('\n                    function(){\n                        this.terms.forEach(function(item){\n                        emit(item, 1)\n                    })\n                }\n                ', {})), ('reduce', Code('\n                    function(key, counts){\n                        return Array.sum(counts)\n                    }\n                ', {})), ('out', SON([('replace', 'reconversations_topic_3'), ('db', 'wcterms')])), ('query', {'topic': 'reconversations_topic_3'})]) on namespace indexes.$cmd failed: 24: Too many open files
```

What could be the reason for such an error?

Answer (score 5):

As per documentation, you going to have increase the `ulimit`. You can do this by running the command below at the system prompt.I have used the recommended value, but you can increase it if needed.

```
ulimit -n 64000
```

After you run this command you need to restart the MongoDB service.

Comment: I am on a mac El Captial. I think there seems to be a restriction on how large I can define ulimit, When doing ulimit -n 64000, i am getting the following error : /usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

Comment: thank you Jaco. You rock. My server is in debian, so your solution worked perfectly.